# I need help analyzing a soil test result for a tomato and herb garden

Tags: tomatoes, herbs

I attached a photo of the soil results. I have a raised bed with tomatoes, and herbs, basil, rosemary, and oregano. I see the nitrogen is low so I will be adding Burpee Organic Blood Meal. Many of the nutrient levels are high, is this a problem? My compost consist of Maryland clay soil mixed with horse manure, grass and leaves. All of it was mixed last fall.
[image: photo of the soil results]

Comment: You might not know that all blood meal products are considered organic and all are essentially the same thing in different colored bags. You might be over-paying for the Burpee product, which may be priced higher because it's a brand name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High levels are not generally a problem .
The plant roots absorb the materials they need. If I wanted only nitrogen , I would add urea. Or many high nitrogen lawn fertilizers are primarily urea.

Comment: Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0):

My granddad used to often add [NH4NO3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_nitrate) and I read advice to do so to this day. Applied once at the beginning of the vegetative period and once again around it's peak. Dug shallowly into the soil. Never apply while fruiting.